# ¿Existe una forma de cerrar/reabrir los módulos importados?

Tags: python, librería, modulos

**Resumen:** ¿Existe una forma de cerrar/reabrir los módulos importados?

Estoy realizando un proyecto personal, y para ello necesito importar un módulo creado por mí mismo para acceder a la información guardada en una lista de forma cambiante, así que escribo una y otra vez sobre el archivo. Mi problema va a la hora de actualizar esa información, si hubiera una forma de cerrar lo el módulo importado y abrirlo nuevamente me serviría de mucha ayuda. Por favor díganme si hay manera, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los módulos son para tener código. Si quieres datos, mejor léelos desde un fichero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar decir que **es mucho mas sencillo y apropiado utilizar ficheros o bases de datos para almacenar datos** (texto plano, *json*, *xml*, `pickle`, etc). Dicho esto:

El módulo `sys` tiene un atributo `sys.modules` que es un diccionario en el que se almacenan las referencias a los módulos importados. Observa el siguiente ejemplo:

```py
import sys, os

print(os is sys.modules['os']) # True
```

Para forzar a *python* a recargar un módulo puedes eliminarlo de `sys.modules`:

```py
import sys

import os

del sys.modules['os']

import os
```

Ten en cuenta que `import os; del os; import os` no recarga el módulo, tienes que eliminar la referencia en `sys.modules`.

Veamos un ejemplo práctico:

```py
import sys, time

i = 0

while True:

    # Creación / Modificación del módulo
    with open('mod.py', 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'x = {i}')
    
    # Eliminar referencia al módulo si existe para que vuelva a cargarse con "import mod"
    if 'mod' in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules['mod']
    
    # Importar el módulo
    import mod

    print(mod.x)

    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

En este ejemplo tenemos un bucle infinito en el que se crea el módulo `mod` *en tiempo de ejecución*. Este módulo solamente contiene una variable `x` que toma el valor de `i` en cada iteración (reescribimos el módulo en cada iteración).

Antes de importar a `mod` comprobamos si existe una referencia a este módulo en `sys.modules`, en tal caso eliminamos dicha referencia.

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias!
Me di cuenta que estaba formulando mal la pregunta, y del y sys me sirvieron para el propósito. No sé manejar bases de datos, y lo hago por la facilidad que me da, sólo estoy empezando en este mundo, pero voy a investigar. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro entonces! Yo tampoco se de bases de datos, siempre queda algo por aprender. Un saludo! ^^

Answer (score 2):

La forma estándar de recargar un módulo en Python es utilizar la biblioteca estándar `imp` en la forma siguiente:

```
import imp
import tu_modulo

[...]

imp.reload(tu_modulo)
```

El primer `import tu_modulo` causará la ejecución de ese módulo (y dejará definido el símbolo `tu_modulo`). Si vuelves a ejecutar `import tu_modulo` en cambio el contenido de `tu_modulo.py` no volverá a ser leido, pues ya ha sido cacheado.

Sin embargo `imp.reload(tu_modulo)` fuerza a que el contenido de `tu_modulo.py` sea ejecutado de nuevo, y las variables y métodos descritos en ese módulo serán sobreescritos respecto a los que Python tuviera cacheados del `import` anterior (pero en cambio no eliminará símbolos que formaran parte del viejo `tu_modulo` y ya no estén en el nuevo).

Esto tiene su utilidad cuando estás ejecutando comandos en un intérprete interactivo, como Jupyter Notebook, y quieres volver a importar un módulo porque has modificado el código del mismo. Ya que Jupyter mantiene una sola sesión activa del intérprete (un *kernel*), un `import` normal no funcionará mientras que `imp.reload()` sí.

No obstante no está claro de qué modo esto te sirve para lo que mencionas en la pregunta (guardar una lista que vas construyendo). ¿No sería para esto más adecuado usar el módulo `pickle` que permite volcar a fichero cualquier estructura de datos Python y recuperarla después? ¿O serializar como JSON los datos?

Comment: No conocía `imp.reload`. Esta es una mejor manera de hacerlo. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias.
La verdad estaba pensando en evitar procesos de más, como analizar la información de un fichero, y dado que constantemente estaré trabajando con una lista, aprovechar las funciones para manejar los datos temporalmente me vendría muy bien, y con formato texto se me complica, o convertirlo a una estructura de datos en python podría gastar más recursos a medida que le agrego más información, y cada vez que inicie el programa hará lo mismo, es con el fin de economizar recursos. Al parecer eso no funciona a la hora de actualizar variables o con la sentencia from. Igualmente gracias

Comment: Guardar una lista es tan sencillo como `pickle.dump(lista, fichero)` y recuperarla es simplemente `lista = pickle.load(fichero)`. Realmente no añade ninguna complejidad ni necesitas analizar nada en el fichero, ni inventar estructuras de datos (una lista es a fin de cuentas una estructura de datos válida). Creo que es mucho más simple que andar recargando módulos, lo que además podría tener otros efectos secundarios.

Comment: muchas gracias, estoy investigando. Me has servido de mucha ayuda.